# flutter swiper controller is giving null value

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am using flutter swiper and assigning the controller to it and later when i print the value of `controller.index` then it prints null.

**My Code:-**

```
SwiperController controller=SwiperController();

Column(
              children: [
                TextButton(onPressed: ()=>print(controller.index), child: Text("Print")),//here am printing the value
                SizedBox(height: 10,),
                ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                  child: Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.8,
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.8,
                    color: const Color(0xff222121),
                    child: Swiper(
                      controller: controller,
                      itemCount: 3,
                      loop: false,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      itemBuilder: (context,index){
                        return card(index);
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing the controller in `initState()`

```
@override
void initState() {
   controller = new SwiperController();
}
```

Comment: I have tried it as well, Still it is printing null